# Union fields in a query

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a table with fields A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3 and B4. I need a select statement that union field : A1 and B1 in C1, A2 and B2 in C2,A3 and B3 in C3,A4 and B4 in C4

for example:

```
 TABLE ONE
 A1 A2 A3 A4 B1 B2 B3 B4
 1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
 2  2  2  2  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  3  3  3  3
```

I need a result like this:

```
 TABLE TWO
 C1 C2 C3 C4 
 1  1  1  1
 2  2  2  2 
 3  3  3  3
```

Comment: And what would be the result if A1 = 1 and B1 = 1, or A1 = 1 and B1 = 2, or for 1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0, or 1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1?

Comment: Come to think of it, what would the result be for 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 and 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1?

Comment: Look, I think almost everything told you your data structure is weird, does not scale up, and would only cause more and more problems. Starting with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179634.

Maybe you'd reconsider the structure itself ?

Comment: Thank you Mark for suggestion.In my case if fields a1..a4 have a value <> 0  b1..b4 have a 0 and if b1..b4 have a value <> 0 a1..a4 have a zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this

```
select A1, A2, A3, A4 
from yourtable where a1+a2+a3+a4 > 0 
union all 
select B1, B2, B3, B4 
from yourtable where b1+b2+b3+b4 > 0
```

Comment: now make A1 = -1000 and that row would not be shown at all :-D

Answer (score 0):

should be easy like:

```
SELECT A1 AS C1
      ,A2 AS C2
      ,A3 AS C3
      ,A4 AS C4
  FROM table_one
 WHERE A1 != 0 
   AND A2 != 0
   AND A3 != 0
   AND A4 != 0
UNION ALL 
SELECT B1 AS C1
      ,B2 AS C2
      ,B3 AS C3
      ,B4 AS C4
  FROM table_two
 WHERE B1 != 0 
   AND B2 != 0
   AND B3 != 0
   AND B4 != 0
```

Comment: This would not produce the expected result, as it would introduce rows with values 0, 0, 0 ,0 (3 of them with the sample data)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i've added the where clause